# How to skip directories in os walk Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, os.walk

I have written an image carving script to assist with my work.  The tool carves images by specified extention and compares to a hash database.

The tool is used to search across mounted drives, some which have operating systems on.

The problem I am having is that when a drive is mounted with an OS, it is searching across the 'All Users' directory, and so is including images from my local disc.

I can't figure out how to skip the 'All Users' directory and just stick to the mounted drive.

My section for os.walk is as follows:

```
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        if re.match(pattern, name.lower()):
                appendfile.write (os.path.join(path, name))
                appendfile.write ('\n')
                log(name)
                i=i+1
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: is `All Users` the name of the directory?

Comment: apologies the path i want to skip is always C:\Users\All Users

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `All Users` is the name of the directory, you can remove the directory from your `subdirs` list, so that `os.walk()` does not iterate over it.

Example -

```
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    if 'All Users' in subdirs:
        subdirs.remove('All Users')
    for name in files:
        if re.match(pattern, name.lower()):
                appendfile.write (os.path.join(path, name))
                appendfile.write ('\n')
                log(name)
                i=i+1
```

If you only want to *not walk* for `All Users` inside a particular parent, you can include the check for that as well in the above `if` condition.

From [`os.walk` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) -

> **os.walk(top, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=False)**
>
> Generate the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up. For each directory in the tree rooted at directory top (including top itself), it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames, filenames).
>
> When topdown is True, the caller can modify the dirnames list in-place (perhaps using del or slice assignment), and walk() will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in dirnames; this can be used to prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting, or even to inform walk() about directories the caller creates or renames before it resumes walk() again. Modifying dirnames when topdown is False is ineffective, because in bottom-up mode the directories in dirnames are generated before dirpath itself is generated.

`topdown` is normally true, unless specified otherwise.

Comment: Will this skip all sub-directories within 'All Users'?

Comment: Yes it will skip sub-directories within 'All Users' as well

Comment: @adrianus Did you even try this? It will never walk to `All Users` directory, no files or folders from it would be read

Comment: Yes, I tried this, and all the files from the directory that is excluded still show up.

Comment: that would not happen unless you have some other issue in your code.

Comment: When you remove a directory from the `subdirs` name, it does not go inside it (walk inside it).

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. It will not walk though that directory and the files will get excluded, that is the correct solution.

Comment: Would really like the other downvoters to comment why they think this is a bad solution.

Answer (score 2):

if you have more than one directory to remove you can use a slice-assignment in oder to remove excluded directories in the `subdirs`

```
excl_dirs = {'All Users', 'some other dir'}

for path, dirnames, files in os.walk(root):
    dirnames[:] = [d for d in dirnames if d not in excl_dirs]
    ...
```

as [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) states:

> When `topdown` is `True`, the caller can modify the `dirnames` list in-place
>   (perhaps using `del` or slice assignment), and `walk()` will only recurse
>   into the subdirectories whose names remain in `dirnames`; ..

Comment: why must like this [:] ?

Comment: @AbdullahSaid added a bit of explanation. additionally: this is a slice assignment; it modifies the list in-place (i.e. does not create a new list).

Comment: Thanks for this info:  

When topdown is True, the caller can modify the dirnames list in-place (perhaps using del or slice assignment), and walk() will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in dirnames;